# How do I have similar multiple panels of GUI to appear on my Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

I have a c# windows form application that has a similar GUI functionality as MSN. It works in the way such that only a notification window appears if there is notification which in this case I have put several buttons and other stuffs in a single panel. (is this the right way to do so?)

How do I code it such that I can use a arrayList to add similar panels to the list and use a for loop to call it out. Example would be calling 2 or 3 similar panels through the use of arraylist(?) and for them to appear below one another. (Maybe like how MSN notifications window comes up one above another.)

the code for the panel is

```
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lblImage);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lblName);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lblLinkName);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lblLinkLocation);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.lblLocation);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 134);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(506, 100);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 17;
```

do I have to code the for loop in the designer file or the coding file? as after I have tried to add for loop in the designer code file, the designer view sort of unable to display my UI.

Comment: Can you provide more clarification? Any sample link of the look you want to create?

Comment: Are you just trying to add multiple panels, all with identical buttons and labels and size, but different locations and tab indexes?

Comment: @daryl : yes that is what i am trying to do. everything simlar but with different location.

Comment: This is what UserControl was made to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for

```
for(int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++){
    AddPanel(panels[i], i);
}

AddPanel(System.Drawing.Point point, int tabIndex){
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    this.Add(panel);
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label("Image"));
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label("Name"));
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label("linkName"));
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label("linkLocation"));
    panel.Controls.Add(new Label("location"));
    panel.Location = point;
    panel.Name = "panel" + i.ToString();
    panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(506, 100);
    panel.TabIndex = tabIndex;
}
```

You'll need to populate the panels array with a the points you'd like your panels to be added at.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. how do I specify the point which they are to be added at for different panels?

Comment: and is all this codes meant to be put at the designer file or the cs file?

Comment: @Thomas Just create you're array and add  your points you want your panels to show up at...

Point[] panels = new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 0), new Point(0, 100), new Point(100, 100) };

Don't put it in the Designer file because VS will remove it, or it will break the editor.  It goes in the form.cs file, after the InitializeComponents() method.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Custom Control that has the interface you want for each item.  Have the Control expose properties, methods, and events that allow you to access the child controls in a constant manner.

You can create multiple instances of the custom control and add them to a List and attach event handlers to them, etc...

If you use a flow layout panel as the parent and add each instance of the custom control to it, it will automatically handle the layout for you without you having to manually position them.  If the flow layout is inside a container with autoscroll set, you will have a nice scrolling list of whatever kind of Items you can dream up.

**adding example**

With a custom control called ListItem.

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
someFlowPanel.controls.add(item);
```

You should probably set item's width to the width of the flow panel you add it to, and set it to anchor left and right.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. how do i add each instance of custom control to it? does it mean that i can add several panels of similar buttons labels and buttons into the flow layout panel?

Comment: If you group all your controls that you want to repeat for each item in to the custom control you can deal with them all as a single grouped item.  You can have as many instances of your custom control as you like.

Comment: hi am i suppose to code all this in the designer file or the cs file?

Comment: The Custom Control can be edited in the designer.  The code to create instances of it and add it to the panel should be in your code file for whatever form you want to add the panels to.